# MD5 Hash seperated by colon?

Tags: sql, database, md5

Is this is a MD5 Hash separated by a colon or a different type of encryption in the "users" table, "password" column?

5cf1c1999a1b01d1d5d4ec6b878c6793:sTfmZLILkh16fyxMHpR8vfCsV7CYuRIV

Comment: Could mean more or less anything. I guess without further context this is unanswerable.